# pyqt - activate QCompleter after a certain number of letters in QLineEdit

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to have a QCompleter that begins to predict only after a certain number of letters in QLineEdit. I wrote simple classes from QLineEdit and QCompleter but I don't know how to add this functionality.

```
class Completer(QtWidgets.QCompleter):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Completer, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.setCompletionMode(QtWidgets.QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        self.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchStartsWith)


class LineEditCompleter(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LineEditCompleter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.completer = Completer(self)
        self.setCompleter(self.completer)
```

I tried to override the `textChanged` from `QLineEdit` to `setCompleter(None)` if the length of text is less than 3 and activate it again if more than to 3 but it does not work, it seems the completer is deleted if I use `setCompleter(None)`.

Is there a possibility to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is pretty well explained [blog](https://john.nachtimwald.com/2009/07/04/qcompleter-and-comma-separated-tags/)  , But yeah you need to re implement QlineEdit and QCompleter to get what you looking for. If you are not able to find what you looking from that blog post let us know.

Comment: That blog post does not answer the OPs question at all. Did you actually try the code?

Comment: @Achayan, I did not find what I was looking for in this blog.